# Validation For NotePad New Line and Email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a requirement where I've to validate email addresses (Correct email format) and each line excluding **comma(,)** , **semicolon(;)**, **spaces(" ")** in a notepad. So I've done the following that seems to be not working accordingly:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"" + email + "");
string line = file.ReadLine(); 

if ((line == null || line.Contains(";") || line.Contains(",") || line.Contains(" ") || line.Contains(email) != IsValidEmail(email)))
{
   return "Check your file. Invalid format!";
}

public bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
       MailAddress emailAddress = new MailAddress(email);
       return true;
    }
    catch
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't validate the email addresses but it does validate the following I mean the first line:

```
at-2017@yahoo.com; we@yahoo.com //Invalid format
at-2018@yahoo.com
```

But this doesn't get validated if the semicolon is in the next line and saves it into the database table:

```
at-2017@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com;//Doesn't validate
```

It's simple but may be I have done something wrong that's I am trying to figure out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So you have something like comma/semicolon separated file? On each line can be 0-n addresses?

Comment: No @Tomas Jakl. Each line should have only one email address and each line should have no comma, semicolon or spaces. Even invalid emails should be validated in each line.

Comment: Are you only reading the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though you are only reading the first line of data from your file. Try this:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"path to file"))
{
    //do validation for each line
    if (IsValidEmail(line) //etc)
    {
        // do something once line is valid.
    }
}
```

If encoding is an issue, there is an overload of this method where your can specify it:

[File.ReadLines() MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383357(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for it @Ric. I missed the `foreach` loop to validate :D

Comment: You’re welcome. The other answer was also good and used similar code to yours with the addition of the while loop. Both do the job.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
void Main()
{
    var file = @"at-2017@yahoo.com;
we@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com
at-2017@yahoo.com
at-2018@yahoo.com;";

    using (var memory = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file)))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var email = new StringBuilder(line)
                .Replace(";", string.Empty)
                .Replace(",", string.Empty)
                .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
                .ToString();
            var isEmailValid = IsValidEmail(email);
            Console.WriteLine($"{isEmailValid,-5}: {email,-20} original: {line}");
        }
    }
}

bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
{
    // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
    return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, @"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"); 
}
```

Result:

```
True : at-2017@yahoo.com    original: at-2017@yahoo.com;
True : we@yahoo.com         original: we@yahoo.com
True : at-2018@yahoo.com    original: at-2018@yahoo.com
True : at-2017@yahoo.com    original: at-2017@yahoo.com
True : at-2018@yahoo.com    original: at-2018@yahoo.com;
```

Comment: Good answer, but, as `line`  is a `string` already, why construct a `StringBuilder` for each line read?

Comment: May be it's my habit concatenate unknown number of strings (Originally I supposed more e-mail addresses in one line). Finally there could be only 1 e-mail address so I agree, the ```StringBuilder``` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` condition like below :

```
if ((line == null || line.Contains(";") || line.Contains(",") || line.Contains(" ") || !IsValidEmail(line)))
```